# Amazon S3 copyObject via Ajax PHP Failed

Tags: javascript, php, amazon-web-services, codeigniter, amazon-s3

I'm learning cloud storage with amazon. here I have difficulty copying files between folders in the bucket. I did access to copy files via ajax and processed in php (Codeigniter 3)

I tried the copyObject function directly through php and it worked, but if it went through the ajax process it failed. is there an error or something i missed?

I have also given permission for this bucket

```
 {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "xxx",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "xxx",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxx:root"
            },
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Error after submit via Ajax:

```
Error executing "CopyObject" on "https://bucket.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/folder/file.jpg%0A"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `PUT https://bucket.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/folder/file.jpg%0A` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Anonymous users cannot copy objects.  Please authenticate.</Message><RequestId> (truncated...) AccessDenied (client): Anonymous users cannot copy objects.  Please authenticate. - <Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Anonymous users cannot copy objects.  Please authenticate.</Message><RequestId>123</RequestId><HostId>123</HostId></Error>
```

Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
      url: base_module+'changeStatus',
      type: 'POST',
      data: { 
        id,
        status 
      },
      success: function(result) {
        $("#data").bootgrid("reload");
        $('#modal-view').modal('toggle');
      },
      error: function(jqxhr, status, exception) {
        $.alert('Exception:', exception);
      }
  })
}
```

POST Function:

```
public function changeStatus(){
    $post   = $this->input->post();
    $id     = $this->crypter->decode($post['id']);
    if($post['status'] == 'accept'){
        $draft = $this->db->get_row($this->tabel,['id' => $id]);
        if(!$draft) return false;

        if($draft['attachment_url']){
            $s3 = copyS3Image($draft['attachment_url'],'folder',$this->config->item('s3_bucket_name'));
            if($s3) $data['attachment_url'] = $s3;
        }
```

copyS3Image Function:

```
function copyS3Image($tar_file='',$folder='',$s3_name='myBucket') {
    if($tar_file!=''){
        //Create a S3Client
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $CI->load->library('aws');
        $credentials    = $CI->aws->getAwsCred();
        $s3Client       = new Aws\S3\S3Client($credentials);
        $bucket         = $s3_name;
        $file_name      = basename($tar_file);
        $file_path      = $tar_file;
        $uri_path       = parse_url($file_path, PHP_URL_PATH);
        $uri_segments   = explode('/', $uri_path);

        try{
            $params = [
                'Bucket'       => $s3_name,
                'CopySource'   => "$s3_name/$uri_segments[1]/$file_name",
                'Key'          => "$folder/$file_name",
                'CacheControl' => 'max-age=3600',
                'ACL'          => 'public-read'
            ];
            $res = $s3Client->copyObject($params);
            echo json_encode(['status' => true,'message' => [],'data' => $res['ObjectURL']]);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            exit(json_encode(['status' => false,'message' => $e->getMessage(),'data' => []]));
        }         
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: "Anonymous users cannot copy objects" seems pretty clear. Your permissions set gives your AWS root account full permissions; presumably `$CI->aws->getAwsCred()` is not authenticating as that root user.

Comment: @ceejayoz thank you for responding to this problem. i also think so, but when i use it without ajax it runs smoothly.